# Cassandra token encoding algorithm

Tags: cassandra

When I make write to Cassandra, it brings my row key, calculates token and then puts it to the node which one responsible for the certain token range. What algoritm Cassandra uses to calculate token?

Comment: If you are minusing the question, feel free to add a note. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cassandra 1.2, the default is the Murmur (version 3) hash.  In earlier versions, Cassandra used MD5.

Comment: You man is amazing. You have an answer to any Cassandra related question whenever I wanted it. Thanks!